# Adding a user brings up an old user UPN

Tags: user

When trying to add a new user that has the same last name as a terminated user, the new user will not add and the terminated user shows up...is there anyway to delete the terminated users profile? The terminated user is no longer listed in AD and sharepoint does grab the new users name but shares the site in the old users name.

Answer (score 1):

This is because somehow the old user's profile is still present in the User profile database. 
Try doing this .

Load your user profile service application using PowerShell. You will get the script from here.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/update-user-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

Once you load the userProfileManager , run the following command :-

$UserProfileManager.RemoveUserProfile($AccountName) .

Enter the terminated account name in $accountname .

$userProfile.Commit()

After this try adding the new user.
Let me know if this does not work.